# Is there a listener for ScrollView's scrolling?

Tags: android

I have a TableLayout inside a ScrollView, because of some special needs, I need to do some things when the ScrollView has reached the top. Is there such a listener to listen in on user's scrolling operations? Or, if there is no a ready listener, can I subclass the ScrollView (which will be painful I supposed) to achieve that? What methods do I need to implment? So far, I don't see a solution to this, but I hope it's only because I missed something .....

Thank you!

(In case you're wondering why I want to do this, here is some more background:

I have a flat-file database, I use a TableLayout to show the query results. When the query generates thousands of rows, the time spent on populating the table (using TableLayout.addView() to add rows) becomes unacceptable -- one minute on the emulator! And, there is a special need that when the table shows up, it has to be put at the LAST PAGE. That is, I have to populate the last few rows first, then grow upward, while the display remains unchanged when the table is growing. I tried two approaches so far, none was satisfactory. So I had to downgrade the requirement a little --- I don't populate all 3,000 rows at once, instead, I populate only the last couple of pages, like the last 40 rows or so. This way, the user will see the results displayed immediately. Then, if and when he decides to scroll up, when the program sees it, then I populate a few more pages, etc. Therefore, I need a listener or some way to detect when the table or the scroll view has reached the top. Thank you for reading up to this far!)

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a TableLayout instead of a ListView with a CursorAdapter, which takes care of the issues relating to viewing large sets of data (scrolling, reusing view elements, not querying all the data at once)? It seems like you're really just making life hard for yourself this way, when Android can do the hard work for you.

Comment: @Yoni Well, the thing is, I'm new to Android. I saw the term Cursor a few times, I thought it's tied to the system-provided database (whatever name it's called, but Android does seem to have a built-in DBMS of some sort), not any proprietary database. Thanks for the tip, I'll look into it.

Comment: It's worth noting, you can write your own Adapters using whatever proprietary DB you want to. And I'd imagine a lot of the slowdown with your data is related to pregenerating 3,000 Views, not to the actual database query, so you may be able to get away with loading your data into a normal `ArrayAdapter`, too.

Comment: @Yoni Yes, you're right, the time is wasted on generating the views, not the data (that's the good thing about a flat-file DB). I guess I'll have to give up the TableLayout and switch to ListView.

Comment: don't think of it as giving up, think of it as simplifying your own life, while learning a bit about some Android classes that can do some of the heavy lifting for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into extending a BaseAdapter http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html and override `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`.
In that method you can check the position. So if you start out by populating your list with 10 items and the position is 10 then you know you've reached the bottom of your list and can add more items to your list. You know your at the top of your list if the position is 0. There's also a method in ListView to have your items start at the bottom ( like the messenger app ) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setStackFromBottom(boolean).

Comment: Thatnks. I just checked the getView() method, there is no explanation about thie method at all. But from your words, I gather that this method is called when a view is about to be displayed, am I right? But can an ArrayAdapter be adapted to a table? I'm new to Android, I've used ListView once with an ArrayAdapter. But I don't seem to have seen in TableLayout's documentation that they can use ArrayAdapter too. ??

Comment: @wwyt Sorry, the fact that you're using a table layout inside of a scrollview slipped my mind. I would definitely recommend changing from a TableLayout to a ListView if I were you. The reason is that the ListView was built to deal with huge data sets like your requesting. You are right about what getView() does. When that's called you can return a view filled with the information you want in it for that given position/row. If it's not to complicated, try changing your TableLayout/ScrollView to a ListView.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, after your and Yoni's replies, which were just in a few minutes, I realized that TableLayout was really not a good choice! I really need to swtich to ListView. So, thanks to you both, I'm now trying to get the "Efficient Adapter" sample program to work in mine. Whew! Glad that I didn't keep fighting on the idea of TableLayout, glad that I asked.

Comment: @wwyt I'm glad to hear your going to make the change. You should notice a significant boost in performance. Good luck!